# I need to install two Nuget Packages with diferent dependencies Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, nuget-package

I`m creating an app and i nedd to use Braintree form Paypal and GoogleMaps
the nuget packages use diferent dependencies from Google Maps Base
son i can not intall them

this is the package i need to use from Braintree.Droid

[image]

and this is the error i´m getting

```
Gravedad    Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido
Error   NU1107  Se detectó un conflicto de versiones para Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base. Para resolver este problema, instale o haga referencia a Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base 71.1610.0 directamente en el proyecto utravel.Android. 
 utravel.Android -> Xamarin.Forms.Maps 4.8.0.1269 -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps 71.1610.0 -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base (>= 71.1610.0) 
 utravel.Android -> Naxam.BrainTree.Droid 2.10.0.1 -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Wallet 60.1142.0 -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base (= 60.1142.0). utravel.Android C:\Users\oscar\source\repos\utravel---APP\utravel.Android\utravel.Android.csproj    1
```

these are the dependencies why i´m getting the ERROR NU 1107

Xamarin.Forms.Maps 4.8.0.1269 -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps 71.1610.0
Naxam.BrainTree.Droid 2.10.0.1 -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Wallet 60.1142.0

My question is
is there any way to make both nuget packages work together?

Comment: the problem isnt the difference from google maps, the problem is that naxam.braintree.droid isnt compatible with .netstandard2.0, btw the same is true for googleplayservices.wallet v 60.x

Comment: so what could i do?

Comment: You have to either find an alternative package or engage what you are aiming from another pov